# Close or Fix a broken img tag using PHP

Tags: php, html, tags

I'm having troubles fixing a 'broken' html string, using PHP

I'm facing the common problem of using substr on an html string, which results in broken tags.

I've managed to fix all the broken tags, except the image one, as the tag itself is not complete, it's not even an opening tag,

For example, Suppose you have a string:

```
<div><img alt="foo" title="bar"
```

I'd really want to to add a `>` to close this, and my other scripts know how to close the `div` automatically.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to catch broken `<img>` tags and automatically fix them?

I've seen many solutions including DOMdocument, tidy and HTMLpurifier, but they don't seem to fix this specific problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide an example of your 'broken' HTML? and how did that come to that anyway?

Comment: The example I've posted is pretty much exactly what I'm facing, it's a div with an img tag inside, with the substr cutting it short in the middle before closing.

Comment: it's already provided

Comment: you sure `DOMDocument` doesn't work? i already have an answer, wheres your codes? lets see what you came up with first

Comment: Do you have the <div> close tag or is that missing too? If you have the close tag, you can just do a preg_replace on <div><img [^>]+</div>

Comment: You should try detecting tags before doing a substring, so you cut your string just after the tags

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can repair tags using `DOMDocument`. (Based on example):

```
$html = '<div><img alt="foo" title="bar"';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$out = '';
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $out .= $dom->saveXML($child);
}
echo htmlentities($out);
```

---

- [**Fiddle demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/U99HCm)

Comment: Superb, Thank you for the answer, It seems that my errors were due to encoding and charsets, That's why it was not working for me ! Annoying, but I'm glad it's solved. Thanks!