# Regex for broken HTML matching

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove broken HTML tags like:

```
<p>right here</p>....<iframe class
<b>Very nice</b>...<ifr
```

etc. My rest of the script of *putting content limit on HTML string and closing any open tags* is working fine and this broken tags will always be at the **end** of the string.
So far i achieved is:

```
#<[^>]*#i
```

The problem is that it considers `<iframe` part of `<iframe>` tag as well.

*iframe just for example...*

**EDIT :**
My PHP version does not support DOMDocument, that's why going for regEx. I have implemented [Closing open HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/close-open-html-tags-in-a-string#answer-5982332) for closing any open tags in string but it is allowing broken tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close or Fix a broken img tag using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846098/close-or-fix-a-broken-img-tag-using-php)

Comment: But i don't want to use DOMDocument

Comment: Why not? It's the standard PHP extension for working with potentially broken markup.

Comment: My server is not supporting it, that's why preferring a regex solution at this moment.

Comment: I have implmented this solution for closing any open HTML tags [Close open HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/close-open-html-tags-in-a-string#answer-5982332) but it has a bug and allowing broken HTML tags

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/EaPBwA/3

Comment: @splash58 it is close, but my broken tag will not have any valid tags after it, that's why we need to match `<iframe class="con` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using standard PHP extension is always the Best option. But for those who are into the same problem and restricted by the PHP version, this is the function which perfectly put length limit on any HTML string:

```
/**
 * Crops HTML text ensuring valid HTML
 * 
 * @param string    HTML string
 * @param int       The length up to which HTML string is to be limited
 */
protected function limitHtml($html, $length)
{
  // Ignoring style tags for displayable string length
  preg_match_all('/<style>(.*?)<\/style>/s', $html, $cssMatches);
  $html = preg_replace('/<style>(.*?)<\/style>/s', '', $html);
  // css
  $css = '';
  if ( isset($cssMatches[1]) ) {
    foreach ( $cssMatches[1] as $cmatch ) {
      $css .= "<style>$cmatch</style>";
    }
  }      
  $truncatedText = substr($html, 0, $length);
  $pos = strpos($truncatedText, ">");
  if($pos !== false)
  {
      $html = substr($html, 0,$length + $pos + 1);
  }
  else
  {
      $html = substr($html, 0,$length);
  }

  // Relace The Broken Opened Tag From The the end of String
  $lastCorruptopnArrow = strrpos($html, "<");
  $lastCloseArrow = strrpos($html, ">");
  if ( $lastCloseArrow < $lastCorruptopnArrow ) {
    $corruptHTmlString = substr($html, $lastCorruptopnArrow, strlen($html) - $lastCorruptopnArrow);
    $html = preg_replace('/'. preg_quote($corruptHTmlString, '/') . '$/', '', $html);
  }

  preg_match_all('#<(?!meta|img|br|hr|input\b)\b([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);

  $openedtags = $result[1];
  preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);
  $closedtags = $result[1];
  $len_opened = count($openedtags);
  if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened)
  {
      return $css . $html;
  }
  $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);
  for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++)
  {
      if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags))
      {
          $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
      }
      else
      {
          unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);
      }
  }
  return $css . $html;
}
```

Working perfectly in my case. Open to enhance: [limit_html()](https://github.com/geek92sunny/limit_html/blob/master/limit_html.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use any HTML parser to get correct result, but this is approach with regex, you want

```
(<\w+(?:\s+\w+=\"[^"]+\")*)(?=[^>]+(?:<|$))
```

[**demo and some explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/EaPBwA/5)

usage

```
$res = preg_replace('/(<\w+(?:\s+\w+=\"[^"]+\")*)(?=[^>]+(?:<|$))/, '$1>', $str);
```