# Displaying malformed html with twig

Tags: twig, shopware6

Assume we have a string

```
$mystring = "<b> Hello"
```

How can I display this string using twig while preventing leaking html tags? Or in other word how can I make twig to close tags automatically if they are still open?

I guess `{{ mystring | raw }}` just prints raw text without verifying / purifying.

Comment: This is not the job of a templating engine though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close or Fix a broken img tag using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846098/close-or-fix-a-broken-img-tag-using-php)

Comment: So it would not be "best practice"... but is it possible in general? I mean, it is also capable of stripping tags etc.

Comment: Have a look at [extending twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html). I would suggest you use the answer in the question I've linked and add that function into `twig`

Comment: Please don't add unnecessary tags to the question. For instance [symphony-cms](https://symfony-cms.net/symphony-cms) is no way related to `shopaware`, `symfony` or even `twig`. Also please don't add tags to the title - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Ok I understand this, but changing the title actually changes the question itself...

Comment: No it doesn't, the question is tagged with `twig` - `You should not force a tag into your title. Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sw_sanitize` does this already.

```
{{ '<b> hello' | sw_sanitize }}
```

Produces:

`<b> hello</b`

Internally `\HTMLPurifier::purify` is used, which

> Filters an HTML snippet/document to be XSS-free and standards-compliant.